# HTML DIV / display/ float

Tags: html, frontend, web-deployment

i have no idea how to put yellow(bottom) div exactly under the pink(left) one.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>AutoDealer</title>
        <style>
        .container{
            width: 860px;
            height: 1074px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .nav{

        }
        .wrapper{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .left{
            width: 399px;
            float: left;
            background-color: pink;
        }
        .right{
            height:350px;
            width: 449px;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: blue;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .bottom{
            clear: both;
            width: 399px;
            background-color: yellow;



        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="left">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ultricies aliquet tellus sit amet ultrices. Sed faucibus, nunc vitae accumsan laoreet, enim metus varius nulla, ac ultricies felis ante venenatis justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In cursus enim nec urna molestie, id mattis elit mollis. In sed eros eget nibh congue vehicula. Nunc vestibulum enim risus, sit amet suscipit dui auctor et. Morbi orci magna, accumsan at turpis a, scelerisque congue eros. Morbi non mi vel nibh varius blandit sed et urna.</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="right">
                    <p>Quisque vulputate mi id turpis luctus, quis laoreet nisi vestibulum. Morbi facilisis erat vitae augue ornare convallis. Fusce sit amet magna rutrum, hendrerit purus vitae, congue justo. Nam non mi eget purus ultricies lacinia. Fusce ante nisl, efficitur venenatis urna ut, pellentesque egestas nisl. In ut faucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesque maximus. Quisque a tempus lectus.</p>
                 </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>ucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesq</p></div>
                 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: always put your code into code snippet instead of giving link to external resource. It was made to be use and secondly it helps community members read and understand your questions better.

Comment: when i delete clear:both;  it work, but text inside the "bottom DIV" stay at the bottom, i want it to be at the top of div

Answer (score 1):

`clear: both` is causing the div to do just that, clear both sides and force itself into a position where the blue element isn't right next to it.

Remove that and it'll be right under the one above it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the update code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AutoDealer</title>
  <style>
        .container{
            width: 860px;
            height: 1074px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .nav{

        }
        .wrapper{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .left{
            width: 399px;
            float: left;
            background-color: pink;
        }
        .right{
            height:350px;
            width: 449px;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: blue;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
  .bottom{

            width: 399px;
            background-color: yellow;



        }
.pull-left
{
float:left
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <div class="left">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ultricies aliquet tellus sit amet ultrices. Sed faucibus, nunc vitae accumsan laoreet, enim metus varius nulla, ac ultricies felis ante venenatis justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In cursus enim nec urna molestie, id mattis elit mollis. In sed eros eget nibh congue vehicula. Nunc vestibulum enim risus, sit amet suscipit dui auctor et. Morbi orci magna, accumsan at turpis a, scelerisque congue eros. Morbi non mi vel nibh varius blandit sed et urna.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <p>ucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesq</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Quisque vulputate mi id turpis luctus, quis laoreet nisi vestibulum. Morbi facilisis erat vitae augue ornare convallis. Fusce sit amet magna rutrum, hendrerit purus vitae, congue justo. Nam non mi eget purus ultricies lacinia. Fusce ante nisl, efficitur venenatis urna ut, pellentesque egestas nisl. In ut faucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesque maximus. Quisque a tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know it work, but text inside the "bottom DIV" stay at the bottom, i want it to be at the top of div

Comment: what you are talking . the bottom div should be on top ? , what u expects , if u want to appear on top then u have to move the bottom div to top and top div to bottom why making complicated

Comment: no.. you do not understand, i find solution just put div class="bottom"> into <div class="left"> and modified my CSS .wrapper{
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }.bottom{
            height: 180px;
            width: 399px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }